# RelativeLayout not performing "match_parent" and alignBottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout container, which is not reaching the bottom of the screen and not reaching the left side of the screen also (there is a tiny white line at the end of the RealtiveLayout)..

[image]

Here is the layout .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="-17dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-17dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ListMessageScreen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2.0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_messages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="-16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:background="#ff1a1a"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/messages_screen_left_button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#ff1a1a"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/messages_screen_right_button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp">
        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone have any idea about why is this happening? I tried so many options until now.. The closest that I came, was adding "android:layout_marginBottom="-17dp"" to the root LinearLayout, but even tough I have made this, I still have the problem regarding match_parent of the RelativeLayout..

I'm a little bit lost. Could someone help me, please? Thanks in advance, SO community!

Comment: You have specified padding in the outsermost `LinearLayout`. The `RelativeLayout` is inside of this, so the padding will be used between the `RelativeLayout` and the screen. Also, your outermost `LinearLayout` has `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, but you should probably use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` so that it takes up the whole screen width.

Comment: It was so obvious.. the padding that you mentioned was causing me a lot of trouble.. I made a test here, and I just configured the "layout_marginEnd" to "-17dp" and it worked. It also makes sense your point about the layout_width, but the fact is that the "match_parent" param for the outermost LinearLayout, didn't took the whole screen, even  tough I'm using "match_parent" for the RelativeLayout..
Indeed, the padding for the root LinearLayout, was my headache. Thank you :)!

Comment: Cool! Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified padding in the outsermost `LinearLayout`. The `RelativeLayout` is inside of this, so the padding will be used between the `RelativeLayout` and the screen. Also, your outermost `LinearLayout` has `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, but you should probably use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` so that it takes up the whole screen width.

Comment: Regarding your answer, the padding from the outermost LinearLayout was killing me... Thanks :)!